# Reboot and Select proper Boot device

Tags: boot

When I turn on my computer, the system shows:

**Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key**

When I press a key, it shows up again.

The problem started after installing virtualbox.

I tired to run boot repair, with no success.

Here is output of `sudo fdisk -l` in live usb:

```
elementary@elementary:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes
126 heads, 22 sectors/track, 2825 cylinders, total 7831552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005f247

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1   *        2048     7831551     3914752    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the HDD is not connected properly or SATA cable is damaged.

I was able to get rid of the error after changing SATA cable that was connected to the HDD.